# Looking for large marked datasets in cyber security

Tags: databases

I have built a machine learning model to detect whether a user accessing a server or network is malicious.  I would like to validate the model by using it on training or validation data in cyber security.

The machine learning model is a clustering model that works by detecting anomalies in data.  I hope to find data that documents different types of user access to a server or network.  If so, a subject-matter-expert can look closer at the clusters marked anomalous to verify whether they are comprised of attacks or not.

Since the machine learning model is a clustering model, no training data is required.  Instead, normal behavior in the dataset is established and assumed to not be malicious, and it is hypothesized that anomalous data would likely contain malicious attacks.

Since the machine learning model does not detect specific types of attacks but instead clusters different types of anomalies, it does not matter what type of data is presented (netflow, pcap, server logs, etc).  I only hope that I can find a wide variety of types of datasets to test on.

The only problem is, I do not have a dataset to use.  **Are there large public datasets that I can use to validate my model?**  The dataset should mark the attacks with the type of attack that was attempted.

Comment: Or to say it shortly, if I have correctly read your message, you have built an [anomaly-based intrusion detection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly-based_intrusion_detection_system) (IDS) and would-like to train it. The problem here is that the training is highly dependent on the environment the IDS is running in (non environment dependent patterns are simply included in signature databases): what may be malicious in one environment may be normal and expected in another one.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf not necessarily - he wants to validate a clustering approach, which means it self-trains based on the data - he needs data to test the clustering, not the specific results

Comment: @paul Thanks for the edit, and it helps, but unfortunately, this type of question is off-topic here as a call for specific resources (i.e. "where can I find..?" which falls under 'product recommendations'). As mentioned below, there are a few ML training datasets available. Note that these datasets are not commonly public because of the sensitive data often contained.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are looking for machine learning data sets to train a model on. This resource contains quite a few data sets:

https://github.com/jivoi/awesome-ml-for-cybersecurity#-datasets

One of these might suit your needs.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to train and test a machine learning model on this dataset.  The link you sent has a lot of data.  Are there any particular datasets that you can recommend?  It would be ideal if it specifically tells me what type of attack was attempted.